# Why do these characters remember that event?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*,

> America Chavez asks Doctor Strange and Wong if they have any experience in the multiverse, and Strange replies that there was a recent event involving Spider-Man. Wong seems to be unphased by that affirmation, showing that he knew about it before this scene.

> In "Spider-Man: No Way Home" final scene, though, Doctor Strange tells Peter Parker that after his spell, nobody's going to remember his identity, including Strange, and they even say their goodbyes.

So, why can they now remember that? Do they only remember it was

> about Spider-Man, but nothing more? But if that's the case, then why doesn't MJ and Ned  seem to remember they were implicated with Spider-Man like Strange seems to be?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The spell at the end of *Spider-Man: No Way Home* was only to make everyone forget who Peter Parker is and so in turn forget Spider-Man’s real identity. However, everyone still knows Spider-Man and all that he’s done; they just don’t know the man in the suit.

> **Peter:** They're coming here because of me, right? Because I'm Peter Parker? So cast a new spell. But this time, make everyone forget who Peter Parker is. Make everyone forget... me.
>
> **Stephen Strange:** No.
>
> **Peter:** But it would work, right?
>
> **Stephen Strange:** Yeah, it would work. But you got to understand, that would mean everyone... who knows and loves you... We'd... We'd have no memory of you. It'll be as if you never existed.
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man: No Way Home*</sub>

As far as I know after the spell is cast and everyone forgets we only see MJ and Ned at MJ’s work and they’re not talking about Spider-Man. They’d still be aware of Spider-Man and their involvement with him but they just don’t know who he is; same as everyone else.

Comment: So they would be aware of their close personal relationship with Spider-Man and that they did not know anything about him? Wouldn't that be a little suspicious?

Comment: Wasn't there a scene at the very end where they visit the graveyard and the guy (who, I believe, was taking care of Stark Industries), says something like "thanks to Spider-man"? Might be misremembering.

Comment: @Clockwork Peter talks to Happy and May’s grave, aye. They both say they met her through Spider-Man.